# Custom template page header not loading style.css in wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I am calling the header on a custom template page with `get_header();` but the header loads without the style.css breaking the site. I noticed that if I place the header on top of some code, the style sheet loads just fine, for example:

```
<?php
/*
    Template Name: Sample Template
*/

get_header();

//some code here
```

I need to load the header below some code since I am using a cookie and as of my knowledge, cookies should be generated before any HTML.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't place any code above `get_header()`. Instead, use actions to "hook" and do some work there.

For example, you could use `get_header` action like this:

```
// in functions.php :

add_action( 'get_header', 'set_my_cookies' );
function set_my_cookies() {
    // ... set those cookies
}
```

See http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/get_header

And more about actions: http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API

It might take a bit to get one's head around actions (and filters) at first, but those are crucial concepts in WordPress, so it's definitely worth it!